# Running total query in select statement without views

Tags: sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have to query a set of running total data by month.

```
e.g. 
Month                 Amount            Total
2014-01-01            100               100
2014-01-02            100               200
2014-01-03            100               300
```

The application does not allow to create a view or SP. It is able to select data from a table directly.

```
e.g.
select Month,
       Amount, 
       Total -- This is my problem.
from   Table -- This is a table only.
```

Any ideas are welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OUTER APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  T.Month,T.Amount,T2.Total
FROM    Table1  T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  Total = SUM(Amount)
            FROM    Table1  T2
            WHERE   T2.Month  <= T.Month 
        ) T2;
```

Or a [correlated subquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  T.Amount, 
        (   SELECT  Amount = SUM(Amount)
            FROM    Table1 T2
            WHERE   T2.Month <= T.Month 
        ) 
FROM    Table1 T
```

Comment: That comparison should be on Month

Comment: @shree.pat18 I have changed answer. Check it now

Comment: +1 for APPLY. CROSS & OUTER APPLY are among the most underused, incredibly useful tools in a SQL Dev's workday that I've ever bumped into. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use SQL Server 2012 because it has cumulative sum built-in:

```
select Month, Amount, 
       sum(Amount) over (order by Month) as Total -- This is my problem.
from Table;
```

The correlated subquery method follows a similar structure:

```
select Month, Amount,
       (select sum(Amount) from table t2 where t2.Month <= t.Month) as Total
from Table t;
```

These are usually the two methods that I would consider, because both are standard SQL.  As Vignesh points out you can do it with `cross apply` as well (although as I write this, his query is not correct).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a second way to create a running total:

```
SELECT t.month, t.amount, 
SUM(t.amount) OVER(PARTITION BY t.month ORDER BY t.month
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as [Total]
FROM [yourTable] AS t
```

Comment: Don't work. After googled it is for 2012 but I have 2008. Thank you.